# How to check if curl's http_code is between 200 and 299

Tags: regex, linux, bash, curl

I would like to test a website until it returns with http_code between 200 and 299:

```
  until [[ $(curl --silent -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} -u admin:admin http://mywww:8080/api/v1) = "2[0-9][0-9]" ]] ;do
    printf '.'
    sleep 5
done
```

But it just keeps on looping even though curl returns 202 for example.
I've tried substituting = with -eq when comparing to regex but then it throws an error

> [[: 2[0-9][0-9]: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "[0-9][0-9]")

Comment: not sure about rest of commands, but for regex matching, use `=~ 2[0-9][0-9]`

Comment: For pattern matching, you must *not* quote the right-hand side.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
until [[ $(curl -I --silent -o /dev/null -w %{http_code} -u admin:admin http://mywww:8080/api/v1) =~ 2[0-9][0-9]  ]] ;do
    printf '.'
    sleep 5
done
```

`-I`: Do a head instead of get. Much more efficent, if not blocked by the webserver.

`=~ 2[0-9][0-9]`: Equal Tilde operator that allows the use of regex in an if statement.

Side note: If you dont want to use equal tilde you should lose the qoutes on the pattern.

Comment: You don't really need regex matching, `=` works just fine with pattern matching, but the pattern must be unquoted.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Updated the answer.